# how to redirect user from where user come after sign-in in aws-amplify

Tags: reactjs, redirect, aws-amplify

Can someone tell, How I redirect to user from where he come, after sign-in.
Requirement: if user is not sign-in, so user come in sign-in and user choose to "sign-in with google" and after he sign-in i want to redirect from where he come. ex: /project/new or /user/profile

i am using:
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.2.1",
"aws-amplify": "^5.0.7",

User should redirect from where use come, like user is not sign-in and he trying to open /project/new to create a project, but as he is not sign-in, so he have to sign-in first and after sign-in user should redirect to /project/new.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#confirm-sign-up) documentation to listen to the `signIn` flow.

```
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify';

function listenToAutoSignInEvent() {
    Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload }) => {
        const { event } = payload;
        if (event === 'autoSignIn') {
            const user = payload.data;
            // assign user
        } else if (event === 'autoSignIn_failure') {
            // redirect to sign in page
        }
    })
}
```

With this, you can use `useNavigate` if you're with React, or `router.push` if you're using next.js.